# .NET Sort concurrent requests into a queue

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, queueing

I asked this at Stack Overflow but seeing as it wasn't so much a programming issue as a theory issue it wasn't well received.

I have a program that issues a unique ascending code every time one is requested. All of it is built client side into the console and there are no issues.

However I am trying to integrate the program with a SQL database that stores the unique codes. I don't have a problem with the programming but the theory behind handling multiple concurrent requests and sorting them into a queue.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated and I'm happy to follow up and explain myself here if need be.

Comment: What? This doesn't make much sense. If you want IDs, have the DB generate IDs. If you have concurrent actors, tying them all to some sort of queue or doing sorting is the last thing you want to do...

Comment: Sorting based on what?  First in, first request processed isn't good enough why?

Comment: Why do you need to sort? You could just use an Identity in Sql Server which will give you a unique, ascending id for each item you insert.

Comment: please follow up and explain yourself

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a namespace problem.

If you have identifiers that are "unique," they can also be thought of as unique within a namespace. A namespace must be owned by a single system to ensure uniqueness.

To solve your problem there are a few approaches:

1. Give each client their own namespace. For example, change the identifer from {ascending integer} to {unique client identifier} + {ascending number}. You can also reverse it if you need it to be sortable, e.g. {ascending number} + {client identifier}.
2. Give namespace ownership to the server. Each client would submit a record without an identifier; the server would generate the identifier, store the record, and return the identifier to the client.
3. Use GUIDs which are globally unique. The down side is that they are not sortable.
4. Use a quasi-GUID, e.g. a timestamp including milliseconds. Use an ISO sortable date.  An example identifier would be 20170809125521356, issued on 8/9/17 at 12:55:21 and 356 milliseconds. These are nice because they are sortable, but there is still a small chance of collision.

Comment: Good answer, but the question was not clear, so you are assuming the problem is globally unique identifiers.

Comment: If I only answered unambiguous questions, I think I'd have a reputation of about 6 :)